# Why is there a white panel in astronaut’s fabric headcover they wear inside the hard helmet?

Tags: identify-this-object, spacesuits

Astronauts always have a black fabric headcover worn over their hair or scalp, when they are wearing the spacesuit and helmet for takeoff or EVAs. There’s always a white panel that looks about 3 inches wide, and seems to go from the forehead to the back of the neck. Is this a different type of fabric? What are the benefits of having this white panel? Does it give extra protection?

Answer (score 28):

This is called a [Snoopy Cap.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snoopy_cap)

It's a hood that holds the communications headset to the astronaut's head.

The white portion is elastic fabric to make the cap fit snugly; the black portions are a non-elastic fabric and hold the communications gear.

Comment: Related, but if folks don't know, NASA and Peanuts (Snoopy) have a [long history together](https://schulzmuseum.org/traveling-exhibitions/to-the-moon/)